# Why can't I add a class file as a Forms in my Xamarin project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I created a new class project in shared-code platform to use a module for Prism. I am trying to add a new xaml file with a code behind but it's not letting me add it as an option. How can I add the missing Forms tab on the side menu on my project?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a standard library, it usually doesn't come with `Xamarin Forms`, make sure you have Xamarin Forms added in your dependencies.